# Gnuplot python with 2 list

Tags: python, gnuplot

I've a python script that gives me 2 lists and another who is the reference(the time).
How can I create a graphic with the representation of my first list by the time. And same question for the second list. I need them on the same graphic.

list1 [12, 15, 17, 19]

list2 [34, 78, 54, 67]

list3 [10, 20, 30, 40]     (time in minutes)

How can I create a graphic in png format with these lists?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should search the web for "Python plotting" or similar first, and come back if you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need this package http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/, then run these codes:

```
import Gnuplot
g=Gnuplot.Gnuplot()
y1= [12, 15, 17, 19]
y2= [34, 78, 54, 67]
x= [10, 20, 30, 40] 
d1=Gnuplot.Data(x,y1,with_="line")
d2=Gnuplot.Data(x,y2,with_="line")
#g.plot(d1,d2)   #uncomment this line if you want to see the gnuplot window
g.hardcopy('filename.png',terminal = 'png')
```

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks Bigeagle :)